# Multiple use wp_logout_url() on page cause 'header already sent' error after submit form

Tags: errors, headers, logout

I am using two `wp_logout_url()` echoes on page.
The first one is used in header.php custom theme file, second one is used in another page template file (page-[customslug].php).

On that page i have a form to edit user profile data.
Sending this form cause on result page "headers already sent" error.
To avoid this problem i must remove one from those two lines where i use `<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>`.

```
<?php 

get_header();  <--- first wp_logout_url();

/* page-[custom-slug].php content */ <--- second wp_logout_url();

get_footer; 

?>
```

Why i can't use multiple logout links on one page?

IMPORTANT:

This is how i retrieve the sended form data:

```
<?php 

if ( isset($_POST['btnname']) ) : 

   // saving data stuff

else : 

   // page-[custom-slug].php content

endif;

?>
```

Comment: Really, there is no one who could have any advice?

Comment: wp_logout_url doesn't send any headers according to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/, so probably it's not the cause of the "headers already sent" issue you're having. Unless there's a filter on "logout_url", the code doesn't send any headers..

Comment: I dont have any filter on 'logout_url'. It is sure that the problem is getting by the conflict of receiving `isset($_POST['btnname'])` value, but only when using two `wp_logout_url()`. When I use only one `wp_logout_url()`, on the page with the result the error "headers already sent" appear.